# Fling with NestedScrollView + TextView

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, textview

I can show you better than I can tell you, so here is the structure of my XML code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    <!-- The upper part of the layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
          <!-- some code inside -->
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So, as you can see I have a `ViewPager` which has fragments inside and supports scrolling.

**Problem:**
I have a few fragments and each fragment has its own layout which suppose to scroll down on a fling.

Everything is perfect, everything scrolls smoothly but when I add a `TextView` and wrap it with a `NestedScrollView` it doesn't work as it supposed to. When I scroll down, it immediately stops after lifting my finger off the screen.

Take a look at the code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/castList"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If remove the `TextView` it works.

Do you have any idea what that might be?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem, however, it has a defect. When you drag the `NestedScrollView` all the way down, you can see a little shaking of the `AppBarLayout`.

Here is my solution:

```
public class FixedScrollingBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior{

private boolean isPositive;

public FixedScrollingBehavior() {
}

public FixedScrollingBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    if(velocityY<0 && isPositive){
        velocityY*=-1;
    }
    return super.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY, isPositive);
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    isPositive = dy > 0;
    if(target instanceof NestedScrollView) {
        if (dy > 20 && dy < 50 && isPositive) {
            dy = 250;
        } else if (dy > 50) {
            dy*=5;
        }
    }
    super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed);
}
```

}

And then apply the behavior in the XML file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior=".utils.FixedScrollingBehavior"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Again, there is a bug when you pull the `NestedScrollView` but it's better than nothing.